# Why is my async Python unit test using mock not catching the assertion?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-asyncio, python-unittest

I have a simple Python script `check_all_members.py` that calls the Microsoft Graph API to check some Entra ID groups and their members.

```py
"""Check if a group contains any external users."""
import asyncio

from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

GROUP_OBJECT_ID = "a69bc697-1c38-4c81-be00-b2632e04f477"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = GraphServiceClient(credential)


async def get_group_members():
    """Get all members of a group and check if there are any external users."""
    members = await client.groups.by_group_id(GROUP_OBJECT_ID).members.get()

    externals = [
        member
        for member in members.value
        if member.user_principal_name.lower().startswith("x")
    ]

    assert not externals, "Group contains external users"


asyncio.run(get_group_members())
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for this function and here is what I've got so far.

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, AsyncMock
from check_all_members import get_group_members


class TestGetGroupMembers(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    @patch("check_all_members.client")
    async def test_get_group_members_no_externals(self, mock_client):
        mock_members = AsyncMock()
        mock_members.get.return_value = {
            "value": [
                {"id": "123", "user_principal_name": "user1@example.com"},
                {"id": "456", "user_principal_name": "xuser@example.com"},
            ]
        }

        mock_client.groups.by_group_id.return_value = mock_members

        await get_group_members()

        mock_client.groups.by_group_id.assert_called_once_with(
            "a69bc297-1c88-4c89-be00-b2622e04f475"
        )
```

That seems to work and also fails the test when I change the last assertion. However it should also raise an error since one "user_principal_name" starts with an "x". Unfortunately it doesn't and I cannot figure out why :(

```py
        with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
            await get_group_members()
```

I'm getting the error message and it looks like my returned mock object isn't working properly.

> AssertionError: AssertionError not raised

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I did some more research and it looks like the test is calling the actual function and making the request to the Microsoft Graph API. So somehow my mock isn't working and it is not injected into my test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your mock response structure doesn't match the expected structure returned by `client.groups.by_group_id(GROUP_OBJECT_ID).members.get()`. The `get()` method would typically return an `AsyncMock` object that resolves to a response object, not a dictionary directly. So you should mock the `.get()` method to return an `AsyncMock` which, when awaited, gives the expected dictionary structure.
- The `assertRaises` method is correctly used, but the way the `get_group_members()` function is structured might not be raising the `AssertionError` as expected. It is important to ensure that the assert not externals statement inside `get_group_members()` correctly raises an `AssertionError` when the condition is met.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, AsyncMock
from check_all_members import get_group_members


class TestGetGroupMembers(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    @patch("check_all_members.client")
    async def test_get_group_members_no_externals(self, mock_client):
        # Mocking the response structure
        mock_members_response = AsyncMock()
        mock_members_response.return_value = {
            "value": [
                {"id": "123", "user_principal_name": "user1@example.com"},
                {"id": "456", "user_principal_name": "xuser@example.com"},
            ]
        }
        mock_members = AsyncMock()
        mock_members.members.get = mock_members_response

        mock_client.groups.by_group_id.return_value = mock_members

        # Testing for AssertionError
        with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
            await get_group_members()

        mock_client.groups.by_group_id.assert_called_once_with(
            "a69bc697-1c38-4c81-be00-b2632e04f477"
        )
```

Comment: Awesome! That works :) Thank you very much. I have a little final issue that my original code is being executed whenever I run the test. I added some logging and I see the original call to the Graph API but I also see the tests with the mocks. Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Forget about it :) I made a silly mistake. Your solution works great 

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you.